# Histogram and distribution in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a large number of records showing call duration from various areas and exchange.  the table has 3 key fields such as below:

Calling_number area call_duration(s)

I need to plot call distribution based duration in bucket of 1 second or 5 second with data studio.

Although there is no specific function in Data studio to create histogram with large number of bins I have seen someone had done it before.

Any help or suggestion on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [RANGE_BUCKET](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/mathematical_functions#range_bucket) mathematical function available in BigQuery. This function scans through a sorted array and returns the 0-based position of a given point's upper bound. This function can be useful if you need to group your data to build partitions, **histograms**, business-defined rules, and more.

Very simple example for age histogram below

```
WITH students AS
(
  SELECT 9 AS age UNION ALL
  SELECT 20 AS age UNION ALL
  SELECT 25 AS age UNION ALL
  SELECT 31 AS age UNION ALL
  SELECT 32 AS age UNION ALL
  SELECT 33 AS age
)
SELECT RANGE_BUCKET(age, [10, 20, 30]) AS age_group, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM students
GROUP BY 1
```

with output

```
+--------------+-------+
| age_group    | count |
+--------------+-------+
| 0            | 1     |
| 2            | 2     |
| 3            | 3     |
+--------------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately this does not work with my data.  I have hundreds of thousands of call records with varying duration. Let's say call duration ranges from 0 to 200 seconds and beyond, and I would like to make a histogram with 5 second bin (x-axis).  It would not be practical to write manually 36 buckets or more in the query.

Also how about if my data is in decimal, let's say I have records with values range from 50.00 to 65.00 and I would like to make histogram with bin size of 0.5.  

What would be the suggestion to do the above efficiently?

Comment: your question is quite generic and asking for directions - `Any help or suggestion on how to do this would be appreciated` - so my answer provided it. As of implementation - who said you need to write manually 36  (or whatever it can be) buckets? I didn't. All can be coded. Anyway - I consider my answer is still relevant - so consider at least voting up (if not yet) :o). Meantime, if you will post new more specific question with all related details, etc. I will gladly answer with code matching details of the question.

Comment: OK. I will post more specific question separately